# Си. Перестановка элементов в массиве

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм

Задача достаточно простая, но с реализацией что-то у меня плохо получилось. Дан массив цифр. Нужно переставить нулевые элементы в конец, а ненулевые переместить в начало не изменяя их порядка.

```
for (int q = 0, i = 0; q<arraySize; ++q) {
 if (array[q]) {
  array[i++] = array[q];
 }
 array[i] = 0;
}
```

Этот цикл прекрасно работает если в массиве есть один нулевой элемент, но если их больше, то последний элемент он не меняет на ноль.

Comment: Идея правильная, но не понятно, чего вы ожидали от этого `array[i] = 0;`.

Comment: Вообще моя идея заключалась в том, чтобы передвинуть все ненулевые элементы в начало, а все остальное заполнить нулями. Собственно этого и пытался добиться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас ошибка в том, что неправильно сдвигаются нули в конец. Их нужно либо записывать используя отдельный индекс, который идет с конца, либо (что проще) вставить их потом в конец все сразу. Вот так, например:

```
  #define DIM(x)  (sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]))

  int array[] = { 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4 };

  int i = 0;
  for (int q = 0; q < DIM(array); ++q) {
    if (array[q]) array[i++] = array[q];
  }

  for (; i < DIM(array); ++i) array[i] = 0;  // Вставить перезаписанные нули в конец
```

---

UPD: Как совершенно правильно заметил @AnT, вопрос про C, а не C++. Поэтому заменил `constexpr int arraySize` на макрос `DIM`.

Comment: Ну допустим. Но от какой точки будет идти последний цикл?

Comment: @twinpixxx, от последнего значения `i`. Аргументы `for` могут опускаться, что здесь и сделано.

Comment: Ах да, изначально не заметил, что вы объявляете 'i' вне цикла.

Comment: @twinpixxx, иначе просто бы не скомпилировалось.

Comment: Поэтому и задал такой вопрос =)

Comment: Обьясните джависту, что здесь происходит?):  `constexpr int arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);`

Comment: @Valentyn Hruzytskyi: Вычисляется количество элементов в массиве. Однако раз уж дело почему-то дошло до `constexpr` (в вопросе по языку С?), то тогда уж лучше было бы `constexpr int arraySize = std::size(array)`.

Comment: @AnT Я то понял, что вычисляется размер массива. В джава он вычисляется как-то проще: `final arraySize = array.length();`. Что за делитель в конце( 'sizeof(array[0])' ) и зачем?

Comment: @Valentyn Hruzytskyi: То, что вы назвали массивом в Джава приместо соответствует `std::vector` в C++. Для  `std::vector` все тоже так же просто: `array.size()` и готово. Однако здесь мы имеем дело с "голым" массивом в стиле C. Оператор `sizeof` в С и C++ возвращает размер объекта *в байтах*. Чтобы узнать количество элементов в массиве надо взять размер всего массива *в байтах* и разделить на размер одного элемента *в байтах*. Вот это деление вы и наблюдаете.

Comment: @AnT, спасибо. Вот чем меня манит С, так это таким вот харкором и тесной связью с машиной

Comment: @Valentyn Hruzytskyi: Не надо только преувеличивать связь С с машиной. С уже давным-давно абстрагирован от машин и попытки игнорировать этот факт ведут лишь в тупик "гамнокодинга".

Comment: Это решение, кстати, неверно с абстрактно-философской точки зрения. Оно заполняет хвост массива *новыми* нулями, вместо того, чтобы переносить туда *старые*. Новичок, скорее всего, не заметит разницы, но опытный программист сразу отличит теплый родной нуль от пришедшего со стороны чужака.

Comment: @AnT: "*дело почему-то дошло до constexpr (в вопросе по языку С?)*". Моя ошибка, вы совершенно правы, Поправил.

Answer (score 3):

Общая идея вашего подхода может быть выражена так

```
for (int q = 0, i = 0; q < arraySize; ++q)
  if (`array[q]` нужно перенести в начало)
    обменять местами `array[i++]` и `array[q]`
```

(Такой алгоритм сохраняет относительный порядок элементов, переносимых в начало, но не сохраняет относительный порядок элементов, переносимых в конец. Алгоритмы, которые способны решить задачу in-place с сохранением относительного порядка и тех, и других, весьма нетривиальны.)

Но так как мы знаем, что именно в этой задаче на исходном месте `array[q]` окажется именно `0`, код можно наивно переписать как

```
for (int q = 0, i = 0; q < arraySize; ++q)
  if (array[q] != 0)
  {
    array[i++] = array[q];
    array[q] = 0;
  }
```

Однако такой наивный вариант будет обнулять "ценные" элементы в случае `i == q`. Избежим этого, тем более что в случае `i == q` вообще ничего никуда переносить не надо

```
for (int q = 0, i = 0; q < arraySize; ++q) {
  if (array[q] != 0)
  {
    if (i != q)
    {
      array[i] = array[q];
      array[q] = 0;
    }
    ++i;
  }
```

Готово.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t pos;
for (pos = 0; pos < arraySize; ++pos) {
    if (array[pos] == 0)
        break;
}

for (size_t i = pos + 1; i < arraySize; ++i) {
    if (array[pos] != 0) {
        array[pos++] = array[i];
        array[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Идея правильная, но реализация пока неправильная. Так вы забьете нулями начальные ненулевые элементы.

Comment: Да, первый элемент обнулится

Comment: поспешил, теперь должно быть верно

Answer (score 0):

Реализация мне не очень нравится, но работает

```
    int length = array.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 0){
            for (int j = i+1; j < length; j++) {
                array[j-1] = array[j];
            }
            array[--length] = array[i];
        }
    }
```