# В массиве расставить сначала положительные, затем отрицательные

Tags: c++, c, массивы, алгоритм

Максимально быстро, сохраняя последовательность, не используя сортировку и другой массив. Нулевых элементов в массиве изначально нет.

Comment: Аналогичная задача решалась здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/904173/%D0%A1%D0%B8-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5 Там есть частичное требование сохранения порядка, которое здесь отсутствует, но на эффективность это не влияет.

Answer (score 1):

Вводите два индекса - первый элемент и последний.

Идем с первого вперед, пока индексы не пересекутся.

Если первый положительный - оставляем на месте. Если отрицательный - смотрим на второй индекс. Если там положительный элемент, меняем их местами, и сдвигаем индексы. Если отрицательный - идем вторым индексом к началу до первого положительного элемента, где и выполняем обмен. Если только этот положительный не окажется левее меньшего индекса - тогда все, работа сделана.

Примерно так. Быстро, O(n). Код типа

```
for(int begin = 0, end = /* Последний индекс */; begin < end; ++begin)
{
    if (a[begin] < 0)
    {
        while(end > begin && a[end] <= 0) --end;
        if (a[end] > 0)
        {
            int tmp = a[begin];
            a[begin] = a[end];
            a[end] = tmp;
            --end;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Все, конечно, гениально. Но можно так, чтоб порядок сохранился?

Comment: Можно. Но это - пинок под одно место, что задания надо давать **ТОЧНО**. Это решение **в точности** соответствует вашему вопросу. "Дайте воды попить, а то так есть хочется, что и переночевать негде".